# How to convert DataFrame column to Rows in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.x

I have the following dataset in `df_1` which I want to convert into the format of `df_2`. In `df_2` I have converted the columns of `df_1` to rows in `df_2` (excluding `UserId` and `Date`). I looked up for similar answers but they are providing little complex solutions. Is there a simple way to do this?

**df_1**

```
   UserId       Date                   -7  -6  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
    87      2011-05-10 18:38:55.030     0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    487     2011-11-29 14:46:12.080     0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    21      2012-03-02 14:35:06.867     0   1   0   1   2   0   2   2   0   1   2   2   1   3   1
```

**df_2**

```
day | count
-7   0
-7   0
-7   0
-6   0
-6   0
-6   1
-5   0
-5   1
-5   0 
.    .
.    .(Similarly for other columns in between)
.    .
6   0    
6   0
6   3
7   0
7   0
7   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [pandas melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

```
dataT = pd.DataFrame({"userID":[1,2,3],"date":["2020-01-01","2019-01-02","2020-08-12"],"-7":[0,1,1],"-6":[1,0,0],"-5":[0,0,0]})
```

Input:

[image]

```
dataT.melt(value_vars= ["-7","-6","-5"], value_name="count")
```

Output:

[image]

**Update**

By taking the comment by Benji the code would be:

```
dataT.melt(id_vars= ["userID","date"], value_name="count")
```

With output:

[image]

Comment: Note that the melt function can also use a "blacklist" of columns, id_vars, where the given answer uses value_vars as a "whitelist". So you could do `dataT.melt(id_vars=["userID","date"], value_name="count")` to melt all the subsequent columns